# Slick slider behave like Bootstrap Carousel when sliding to next slide

Tags: javascript, carousel, slick.js

In slick slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), how to hide all slides within the current slide and the desired slide when sliding, just like the Bootstrap Carousel behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you mean by "hide all slides within the current slide and the desired slide" is that you want to hide all slides *between* the current slide and the *chosen* slide. I don't think that Slick supports this effect, so when I've needed to go directly to the next slide, I've used the "fade" option.

```
$('.slideshow').slick({
    speed: 500,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear'
});
```